# What stylometric pecularities are considered to be typical for stephen kings writing?

Tags: style, language, horror

I never read a book written by Stephen King, 
but i heard on many occasions about his style of writing being very unique with regard to his stylometric featurs.

Could you bring some examples for this features?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Can you define "stylometric features" for the purposes of your question? And if you want to know more about Stephen King, why haven't you read his books?

Comment: any linguistic feature which is very frequentive above the average use of other authors, for instance: How long and complicated are the sentences, what is special about the metophors used, how much information about physical characteristics are put into one sentence, is there heavy or sparse use of adjectives, is the syntactical structure used by the author variable or rigid, which phrases (nounphrases, adverbialphrases...) are overrepresented to the average use ...

Comment: I'm sorry; unless this pertains somehow to your own writing, this question isn't on-topic here. We don't do literary (or stylometric) analysis, except as is immediately relevant to solving a writing problem.

Answer (score 1):

The main one I'm aware of is that King often uses *which* to introduce a [restrictive clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness). Grammatical purists reserve *which* for nonrestrictive ones, and introduce restrictive clauses with *that.*

Comment: This trips me up constantly, because I learned the which/that rule when learning Italian, and the rule is unfortunately not the same. I always look at the subject of the sentence, and if it's the same as the clause, I use "which." In that wiki example, I would always write "The puppy which was born yesterday was tiny," because "the puppy was tiny" and "the puppy was born yesterday" have the same subject. "That" just sounds wrong there.

Comment: Hmmm. \*wonders whether Stephen King posts on writers.stackexchange under a clever alias\*